# Approximation of quasi-periodic function by trigonometric polynomials

Tags: harmonic-analysis, almost-periodic-function

The elements of the closure of $\{ \sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{i\nu_j x}: a_j\in \mathbb{C}, \nu_j\in \mathbb{R} \}$ in the supremum-norm are called almost periodic functions. An almost periodic function $f$ is called quasi-periodic iff the frequency module

$$ \mathcal{M}(f)=\left\langle \left\{ \nu\in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x)e^{-i\nu x}dx\neq 0 \right\} \right\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}} $$

is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. By definition we can approximate $f$ in supremum-norm by functions of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{i\nu_j x}$. I'd like to know whether one can preserve the frequencies.

**Question**: Is it always possible to approximate $f$ in the supremum-norm by functions $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{i\nu_j x}$ with $\nu_j\in \mathcal{M}(f)$?

Comment: I would say $\displaystyle\mathcal{M}(f)= \left\{ \nu\in \mathbb{R}: \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t (f(x))^ke^{-i\nu x}dx\neq 0 \right\} $ which is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and I would look at the Fourier transform of $f$ in the sense of distributions

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry, I don't see, how I can use the Fourier transform to get an approximation in the supremum-norm. Could you tell me, how you would proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is Satz XIV, p. 160 of Harald Bohr, [Zur Theorie der Fastperiodischen Funktionen: II, Acta Math. **46** (1925) 101-214](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887596). (Page 162 attributes the quasi-periodic case to Bohl.)

Comment: Thank you, very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.